# Search Box filter in Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Background
HTML Page having navigation on left and body on right. In Navigation, five tabs are there. `ul` is being used and several `li` elements exists in each vertical tab. Each vertical tab has search box to filter the data.

1) HTML Code

```
<h3>First</h3>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="Searchtab1" />   
     <ul id="Firstul">
        <li>Germany</li>
        <li>France</li>
        <li>Sydney</li>    
     </ul>
</div>
```

Script code

```
$("#Searchtab1").on("keyup click input", function () {
if (this.value.length > 0) {
  $("#Firstul li").hide().filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().lastIndexOf($("#Searchtab1").val().toLowerCase(),0)==  0;

  }).show();

}
else {
  $("#Firstul li").show();
}
```

Similarly there are five vertical navigation tab has similar code. Now the problem is there is one requirement to have one global search box on top of these searches i.e. One search box on top of HTML which will filter all navigation tabs. User can further filter on individual tabs. Basic filter is working fine when i search again on individual navigation it lists all elements again. Basically the global search takes precedence followed by local search, it should be able to handle case when user changes anything on Globalsearch/local search, it should change by considering the both search options(global first)

This is what i have tried
[FiddleLink](http://jsfiddle.net/anjsfiddle/p5jxB/1/)
Can someone suggest how to correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Add class (alluls) for all ul elems (or use some jquery selector to select them) and:

```
$("#Searchtab1").on("keyup input", function () {
if (this.value.length > 0) {
  $(".alluls").each(function(){
      $(this).children().hide().filter(function () {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().lastIndexOf($("#Searchtab1").val().toLowerCase(),0)==  0;

      }).show();
  });

}
else {
  $(".alluls li").show();
}
```

Edit: removed click event

http://jsfiddle.net/EchoSin/p5jxB/6/

Comment: It is working same as i coded.  I understand your point that to avoid redundancy you have given same class( i coded twice for both search box).Global search works fine i.e. when i enter any value in global search box, it filters all data but when then i search again in individual text boxes.(first whole data comes) and then it searches on local text by ignoring global text. My requirement is one should be able to search first on global filter and then they can further filter on each. Both text should be considered for search.Fiddle -->[Source Code](http://jsfiddle.net/anjsfiddle/p5jxB/1/)

Comment: You don't need any click events there, remove them.

Comment: Sorry if I am not getting, Can you please explain. If i remove the individual search boxes then once searched on global text box, how can user further search on individual navigations. Can you update the fiddle and show. Thanks. [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/anjsfiddle/p5jxB/1/)

Comment: I am not telling you to remove indyvidual searchboxes. Above in my replay is only a snippet. Just remove click events. Here is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EchoSin/p5jxB/4/

Comment: So what about my solution? Is it working? Here is a little change: http://jsfiddle.net/EchoSin/p5jxB/6/ (when you remove last letter from secondary serch inputs)

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot for your help. I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this **JSFIDDLE**?
Link: https://jsfiddle.net/umaar/t82gZ/

## HTML

```
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" />
    <span id="filter-count"></span>
</fieldset>
</form>

<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Jim James</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hello Bye</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Wassup Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bleep bloop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">jQuery HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS HTML AJAX</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HTML5 Net Set</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Node Easy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Listing Bloop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact HTML5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS3 Ajax</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ET</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>}
```

## JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#filter").keyup(function(){

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

    // Loop through the comment list
    $("nav ul li").each(function(){

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            $(this).show();
            count++;
        }
    });

    // Update the count
    var numberItems = count;
    $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = "+count);
   });
});
```

Granted this isn't your exact answer, made for just you! But I created that fiddle and maybe it can help you! If you want a different fiddle see the above answer! (EchoSin's)

> ```
>      $("#Searchtab1").on("keyup input", function () {
>    if (this.value.length > 0) {
> $(".alluls").each(function(){
> $(this).children().hide().filter(function () {
> return $(this).text().toLowerCase().lastIndexOf($("#Searchtab1").val().toLowerCase(),0)==  0;
>
> }).show();
> });
>   }
> else {
>  $(".alluls li").show();
>    }
> ```
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/EchoSin/p5jxB/6/